# Install Dark Mode for Nuxt.Js

Tags: vue.js, themes, nuxt.js

I want to install a Dark Mode to my Nuxt.Js application (using Vue.Js) so I can change dynamically my theme inside my app.

I'm using Ant as a front-end framework and already posted an issue about methods that I can use to modify **color vars** but I have no answers.

So I was wondering if any of you guys has any idea how to install a Dark Mode using Nuxt.Js

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**2020 Update**

This can be done easily with the @nuxtjs/color-mode library [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt-community/color-mode-module/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/example/pages/index.vue) is an example of this in action

1. Add @nuxtjs/color-mode dependency to your project
2. Add @nuxtjs/color-mode to the buildModules section of your nuxt.config.js
3. Start theming your CSS with .dark-mode and .light-mode classes

You can edit it in nuxt.config.js

```
colorMode: {
  preference: 'system', // default value of $colorMode.preference
  fallback: 'light', // fallback value if not system preference found
  hid: 'nuxt-color-mode-script',
  globalName: '__NUXT_COLOR_MODE__',
  componentName: 'ColorScheme',
  cookie: {
    key: 'nuxt-color-mode',
    options: {
      path: nuxt.options.router.base // https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#base
    }
  }
}
```